# PHP Enable Compressing GZIP

Tags: php, caching, compression, gzip

I have this message from google speed test:

Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 67.4KiB (65% reduction).

```
Compressing http://localhost/english/jquery.js could save 57.9KiB (65% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/javascript/slider.js could save 4.8KiB (71% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/style/style.css could save 3.7KiB (72% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/javascript/home.js could save 1.0KiB (64% reduction).
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

In the configuration of your webserver, you should enable the module/extension that will compress text *(css, js, html, ...)* content that's sent to the browsers.

Typically, if you are using the Apache webserver, you'll have to enable and configure [**`mod_deflate`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

As a sidenote : you will do this in the webserver configuration -- activating compression has pretty much nothing to do with PHP *(CSS/JS are served from the same Apache server that runs PHP scripts, but that's all there is in common)*.

Answer (score 0):

Install mod_deflate to your server & enable it

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<Files *.php>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 5 hours 3 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 5 hours 3 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "modification plus 5 hours 3 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 5 hours 3 minutes"
```

Comment: it does, if mod_deflate is loaded

Comment: I checked on phpinfo() and mod_deflate is loaded, but i copied this code and the google speed test still shows the errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_deflate` on server.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # compress by mime type
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

    # compress certain file / file type
    <Files *.html>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I want to js/css and i tried to change from html to js and its doing nothing :S

Comment: are you sure you have mod_deflate installed on your server?

Comment: Where should I need to check? ( I HAVE XAMPP ), on php.ini?

Comment: Find `httpd.conf` in apache folder (should be in `/conf`), find passage where are `LoadModule`s and find `mod_deflate.so`. If it's commented (with `#` at the beginning of line), uncomment it. If it's not even there, add `LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so` (in case modules are in `module` folder in apache root folder). Restart apache.

Comment: Ok, I enabled :), thanks. Now I need to put a code, you can help me? what i need to change to write *.js and *.css? I tried to put up text/css and text/js and to put <Files *.css and <Files .js and it still dont work

Comment: Just create `.htaccess` in root folder of your web page and put `<IfModule...>`, `<Files *.js>` and `<Files *.css>` in there. Follow syntax I provided in original post.

Comment: I copied your code and add     <Files *.js>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </Files> and it still show the errors :\ Can You come to chat on this website? ( PHP CHAT )

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1749/discussion-between-ondrej-slintak-and-daniel)